# Matlab Question help through an Excel table import

Tags: matlab, helper

The question asks me:

The Excel file attached to this homework titled “HW3_question13.xlsx” contains data from a
certain experiment.
(i) Open “HW3_question13.xlsx” in Excel. Column 1 shows the experimental value and
Column 2 shows the expected value. Plot a line graph for the given data. Add legend
and titles for plot.
(ii)
a. Import the Excel file to MATLAB and plot a graph for the expected value and
the experimental value over the length of the file. (Y axis would be values and X
axis would be length)
b. Specify the line color and styles: red dashed line for experimental data & red
solid line for expected values.
c. Include axis labels and a descriptive title (for example: Experimental value and
Expected value).
d. Include a legend

My MATLab code is as follows:

`
t = [1:50]
x = BE1500HW3question13

```
plot(t,x(1:50,1), 'r--' , t,x(1:50,2),'r');

title('Question 13');
xlabel('Length');
ylabel('Value');
legend('Experimental Value', 'Expected Value')
```

`

*** what's wrong with the code?

It gave me a wrong result saying:

Error using tabular/plot (line 220)
Tables and timetables do not have a plot method. To plot a table or a timetable, use the stackedplot function. As
an alternative, extract table or timetable variables using dot or brace subscripting, and then pass the variables
as input arguments to the plot function.

Error in #filename (line 4)
plot(t,x(1:50,1), 'r--' , t,x(1:50,2),'r');

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `x` is not a numeric array but instead it is a table or timetable. MATLAB cannot directly plot table and to proceed further you have to extract the individual variables from the table and pass them as input arguments. here is the updated code:

```
x = readtable('HW3_question13.xlsx');
t = 1:size(x, 1);
plot(t, x(:, 1).Variables, 'r--', t, x(:, 2).Variables, 'r');
```

You can know more about `readtable` [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/import_export/read-spreadsheet-data-into-table.html)

Comment: Thank you for the help, I tried that but it still gave an error. It states:                                                                             
                                                                                                                                          
 Error using readtable (line 498)
Unable to find or open 'BE1500_HW3_question13.xlsx'. Check the path and filename or file permissions.

Error in Hd7279_BE1500_HW3_Q13 (line 2)
x = readtable('BE1500_HW3_question13.xlsx');

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the `readtable`, you have to either keep script in the same directory as `*.xlsx` file or provide the correct path to the `*.xlsx`.

Comment: Try giving the absolute path like this:
`x = readtable('C:\Users\myPC\Documents\MATLAB\HW3_question13.xlsx'); `